# speed difference between using structs and variables as input arguments of a function

Tags: c, performance, optimization, struct, embedded

To optimize functions which have same pattern, I am considering two ways of implementation.
A environment of this function may used is inside of interrupts on embedded software. This is why I am faced of difficulty since considering of speed capacity is required.
In my opinion, following case 1 and 2 have same speed feature. However my colleague said there might be difference since first case need to access using pointer but second does not.
Which one is more faster?
I need your help to implement efficient code with speed.

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char member1;
  unsigned char member2;
  ..
  unsigned char member10;
} my_struct

my_struct input[10];

void My_ISR1( void )
{
  ...
  sub_func1( input[1] );
  return 0;
}
void My_ISR2( void )
{
  ...
  sub_func1( input[2] );
  return 0;
}
void sub_func1( my_struct my_struct_input )
{
  if( my_struct_input.member1 < my_struct_input.member2 )
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

CASE2)

```
unsigned char member1of1;
unsigned char member2of1;
...
unsigned char member10of10;

void My_ISR1( void )
{
  ...
  sub_func1( member1of1, ..., member10of1 );

  return 0;
}

void My_ISR2( void )
{
  ...
  sub_func1( member1of2, ..., member10of2 );

  return 0;
}

void sub_func1( unsigned char member1, 
                unsigned char member2, ..., 
                unsigned char member 10 )
{
  if( member1 < member2 )
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only way to be sure if one implementation is faster than another, for your compiler, and your problem space, in your code, on your hardware, for your particular use case, is to measure it.

Comment: You are not passing a pointer to the struct, both snippets you posted copy the same amount of data to the stack. You *should* be passing the struct by reference (i.e. using a pointer), instead of copying it every time (like you're doing right now), that would likely be more performant (and probably easier to inline for the compiler). Apart from that, of course you should be using `struct`s instead of duplicating 10s of fields, not just for performance reasons, but to reduce duplication and allow passing any struct instance in the same manner, transparent to the actual consumer.

Comment: There is no access by pointer since you are passing the struct *by copy*.  This kind of micro-optimisation is seldom productive - leave that sort of thing to the compiler and concentrate on optimising at the design level by using efficient data structures and algorithms.  Ultimately the answer to the question "which is faster" can only be answered by measuring it and the answer may even differ depending on compiler, target and compiler options.

Comment: It depends on the number of freely usable processor registers and the quality of the optimizer.  The rough guidance is that you'll have to stop assuming that it can do it still optimally when the struct has more than 4 members or the member types are not simple.  10 is too much.  Just look at the generated machine code.  You'll probably see the caller create the struct on its own stack frame, pass a pointer, and the callee copying the struct into its own stack frame.  The copying makes it expensive.

Comment: If you really care, measure it.  Avoid copying data around; manipulating pointers can be much faster.  Know how your programming languages passes data (that is, when it generates potentially expensive copies).

Comment: Don't worry about such micro-optimizations.  Just write clean code.  The compiler is better at optimizing than you are.  The compiler doesn't need your help.  However, the developer that maintains your code in the future (perhaps your future self) does need your help.  If these 10 variables are members of an object abstraction then they should probably be kept together.  And humans have a limit to how many parameters they can manage in their head and understand.  Ten parameters is too many.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior since you `return 0` from a function with no return value. ISRs obviously don't return anything. This can be disastrous in case a compiler-generated return from an ISR yields different machine code than a regular return from subroutine (as is often the case).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be sure if one implementation is faster than another, for your compiler, and your problem space, in your code, on your hardware, for your particular use case, is to measure it.

However, of the two options presented, I would expect the pass-by-struct to be slightly faster (by the way, in your code you are ***not*** passing by pointer)

In both presented cases, a copy of the variables is passed to the function.
In both cases, this results in a copy of 10 bytes, however given the struct is contiguous, this may be slightly faster.

However, a better option might be to pass by pointer eg:

```
void sub_func1( my_struct* my_struct_input )
{
    if(my_struct_input->member1 < my_struct_input<member2)
    ///........
}
```

This way, instead of copying 10 individual variables, or a struct of 10 bytes, we are only copying one (presumably 32-bit, but it depends) address.

It does have the downside that you are now operating on the exact same struct as the caller, but that can be resolved using `const` pointers.

One further thing to consider, is that while the function call might be faster in one scenario or another, you have to look at the bigger picture. While passing a struct-pointer should be faster, you have to also consider the overhead in constructing the struct - if you have to assign the struct members from existing variables, this obviously adds extra processing, which must be factored into the consideration.

Comment: The struct is only a copy of 10 bytes if the target does not require a higher level of word alignment - it could be 40 bytes for a target that requires 32 bit alignment.  The use of a structure may also prevent passing of some arguments in registers.  There is no answer to this question, there are too many unknowns; it has as you say to be measured.